# Setting up delayed constraint in Minimize, true for every t for each solution

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

I need a solution for `t1, t2, flatR, flatC` that holds `r >= 2*c` true for every `t`.

I want to set up optimization task with a constraint on piecewise inequality that should evaluate to true for every t (for each solution found for target variables - check that it satisfies); but none of the SolveAlways/Satisfiability methods I tried do not work.

```
c = Piecewise[{{flatC, t1 <= t <= t2}, {0, True}}]; 
r = Piecewise[{{flatR, t1 <= t <= t2}, {0, True}}]; 

cond = And @@ {
     10 <= t1 <= 20, 10 <= t2 <= 20, t1 < t2, (* some basic conds *)
     Assuming[
         Element[t1, Reals] && Element[t2, Reals], 
             Integrate[c, {t, t1, t2}] == 5], (* Integrate = 5 *)
    r >= 2*c (* <-- here I want this to be true for every t *)
};

Minimize[{Assuming[Element[t1, Reals] && Element[t2, Reals], 
    Integrate[r, {t, t1, t2}] + Integrate[c, {t, t1, t2}]], cond}, 
  {t1, t2, flatR, flatC}] (* does not work *)
```

Seems that I need to somehow express the `r >= 2*c` as a function, but can't find a way in this setup

Thanks!

Edit:

I removed unnecessary stuff from the problem as suggested in comments:

```
c = Piecewise[{{flatC, t1 <= t <= t2}, {0, True}}]; 
r = Piecewise[{{flatR, t1 <= t <= t2}, {0, True}}]; 

cond = And @@ {
     (* some basic conds *)
     10 <= t1 <= 20, 10 <= t2 <= 20, t1 < t2, flatC*(t2 - t1) == 5, 

     r >= 2*c (* <-- here I want this to be true for every t *)
};

Minimize[{flatR + flatC, cond}, {t1, t2, flatR, flatC}] (* does not work *)
```

Comment: I recommend using `$Assumptions = Element[{t1, t2}, Reals];`, then removing the `Assuming[]` to start with.

Comment: Cleaned up the code a bit to emphasize on the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the future guys, here is the answer. It has two parts.

---

First, to test at each step of `NMinimize` (that is, not analytical solution) - it is essential to use the `?NumericQ` trick http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502 so the resulting function that will prove that `expr` holds true for every `t` would look like:

```
FlatTrueForAll1[expr_, cc_?NumericQ, rr_?NumericQ, nbb_?NumericQ, 
  tt1_?NumericQ, tt2_?NumericQ] := 
 Boole@TrueQ@
   Reduce[expr /. {flatC -> IntegerPart@cc, flatR -> IntegerPart@rr, 
      flatNB -> IntegerPart@nbb, t1 -> IntegerPart@tt1, 
      t2 -> IntegerPart@tt2}, t, Reals]
```

so I used it as:

```
FlatTrueForAll1[r >= 2*c, flatC, flatR, flatNB, t1, t2] == 1
```

in my constraints.

---

The second part, is that in general using functions that do symbolic calculations in NMinimize (in my case proving that the expression is true) is **slow**.

The correct approach to this is to try to solve the original `expr` for all the variables, before the actual calculation is done:

```
FlatTrueForAllSolve[expr_] := 
 Assuming[t1 < t < t2, 
  Simplify[Reduce[expr, {flatC, flatR, flatNB, t1, t2}]]]
```

and use it as:

```
FlatTrueForAllSolve[r >= 2*c],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c = Piecewise[{{flatC, t1 <= t <= t2}, {0, True}}]
r = Piecewise[{{flatR, t1 <= t <= t2}, {0, True}}]
```

Using your comment literally:

**I actually want to find such a solution that holds r>=2*c true for every t in [t1, t2].**

the problem becomes very simple.

For this case `c` becomes `flatC` and `r` becomes `flatR`.

Further, using the condition

```
flatC*(t2 - t1) == 5
```

`flatC` becomes `5/(t1-t2)`.

Using these transformations `cond` becomes

```
cond = And @@ {10 <= t1 <= t2 <= 20, flatR >= 10/(t2 - t1)}
```

and minimizing the sum of `flatC` and `flatR` becomes

```
min = Minimize[{flatR + 5/(t2 - t1), cond}, {t1, t2, flatR}]

(* {3/2, {t1 -> 10, t2 -> 20, flatR -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I actually want to find such a solution that holds `r>=2*c` true for every `t` in `[t1, t2]`. Having a general solution over `t` and as a function of `flatC` does not help, and I need the exact numbers here. The problem statement that I initially posted is not defined correctly in this regard and is not to be solved as-is, despite the correct syntax.

Comment: @grandrew Ok. I have updated according to your latest comment. There is only one solution that fills all the criteria stipulated.